# Why I am getting following error when trying to start SDK manager?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a 64 bit- 20 GB Ubuntu partition which has very less usable space. So I have put Eclipse in my Ubuntu and downloaded sdks to a folder in my another partition. So when I try to start sdk manager, I am getting the following error in my console:

```
Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program "/media/Data/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb": error=13, Permission denied' while attempting to get adb version from '/media/Data/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb'
```

I have run chmod recursively on android-sdks directory. If I change the address for sdks to Ubuntu partition, sdk manager starts successfully.

Is there anything I can do other than increasing the partition size?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.